# "chmod" doesn't work

Tags: linux, chmod

I wrote a /bash script and to execute it I decided to set all the rights, so I tried

```
chmod 777 * //I had 3 text files in the directory, so that's ok
```

Then to check the result I typed

```
ls -l
```

But the rights hadn't changed at all.

I haven't got any error messages and it seems strange. I also tried to specify full path, but this hadn't helped.

I also tried to do all of these steps under root

Where may be the problem?

---

Thank you for help!

---

ls -la

```
drwx------ 1 gemma gemma 4096 июля  20 18:00 .
drwx------ 1 gemma gemma 4096 июля  20 16:35 ..
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma  407 июля  20 18:00 buildedfile.out   ;this is what I
                                                               ;need to launch
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma 4096 июля  20 17:21 kernel.bin
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma  350 июля  20 16:59 link.ld
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma 2025 июля  20 17:59 main.c
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma 1894 июля  20 17:34 start.asm
-rw------- 1 gemma gemma  457 июля  20 17:20 start.o
```

That is what ls shows after all I tried

---

I rebooted PC and problem rose again. But now any of suggested methods doesn't help.

---

I'm using Linux Mint 13 32-bit.
On main disk where this files are located I have ext3, also tried on two another partitions where I have ntfs and FAT32.

---

buildedfile.out is a terminal app written on C

Comment: Did you get an error from the `chmod` command?

Comment: did you try chmod 777 /path/to/folder/*

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la`

Comment: Try the verbose switch: `chmod -v 777 *`

Comment: You can also try `chmod a+x *` (or even better `chmod a+x buildedfile.out`) if that works and you just need to execute a file maybe it's only the `777` thing wich causes trouble :/

Comment: Which filesystem are you using?

Comment: What OS are you using? The tools are slightly different Linux vs. Mac.

Comment: What is buildedfile.out? A shellscript? Try `sh buildedfile.out`. At the other problem: show the output of `mount`. Where is your directory at?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I had this same problem, the partition I was accessing was an ntfs partition mounted with ntfs-3g (with no permission support by default), and it took a while for me to remember that.

I would expect chmod to give me some warning, but it didn't just like in your case.

I know there is an option on fstab when using ntfs-3g to make it possible to set permissions in an ntfs partition as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition).

I hope it helps.

Comment: That can happen on a vagrant box as well which was the case for me. So, I changed the permission of the directory from within host system. Et voila, permission granted on virtual machine. Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: tldr: `mount -o permissions /dev/...`

Answer (score 7):

Try: `sudo chmod -R -f 777 *`

I think that can be a permission issue.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your filesystem is not mounted read only ?

Type *mount* command to check. if there is *ro* in the mount options, you need to remount your filesystem with the following command :

> mount -o rw /dev/ /mountpoint

You can also check which user owns the shell script.

If it's not "gemma" it could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was indeed a problem of my HDD caddy being correctly mounted. I solved it following these steps http://askubuntu.com/a/168424/20868

Answer (score 3):

(Might be the problem of some future readers:) @VinGarcia's answer is correct but specifically in case you're using WSL and you're trying to chmod/chown in "Windows files" mounted on the `/mnt/` path, it is not allowed by default.

In this case, you have two options. Either use the WSL's filesystem  (which is not mounted, e.g., your home at `~`) and it's allowed there, or create an `/etc/wsl.conf` and add this to it:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Then in CMD run `wsl --shutdown`. Re-open a new wsl terminal window and now it must work.