# 'chmod' in WSL doesn't change permissions correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to learn Linux essentials on WSL. I tried to change permission for a test file and it didn't work as I expected.

```
$ stat test.sh

  File: test.sh
  Size: 1616            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: eh/14d  Inode: 93168217291239796  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)   Gid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)
Access: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Modify: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Change: 2019-11-25 12:44:11.615101900 +0600
 Birth: -

$ chmod 444 test.sh
$ stat test.sh

  File: test.sh
  Size: 1616            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: eh/14d  Inode: 93168217291239796  Links: 1
Access: (0555/-r-xr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)   Gid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)
Access: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Modify: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Change: 2019-11-25 12:49:02.544253700 +0600
 Birth: -
```

As you can see, I tried to apply the permission 444, here 555 was applied. Another example,

```
$ stat test.sh

  File: test.sh
  Size: 1616            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: eh/14d  Inode: 93168217291239796  Links: 1
Access: (0555/-r-xr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)   Gid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)
Access: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Modify: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Change: 2019-11-25 12:49:02.544253700 +0600
 Birth: -

$ chmod 711 test.sh
$ stat test.sh

  File: test.sh
  Size: 1616            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: eh/14d  Inode: 93168217291239796  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)   Gid: ( 1000/merajmasuk)
Access: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Modify: 2019-11-25 01:42:24.306619600 +0600
Change: 2019-11-25 12:52:27.316596700 +0600
 Birth: -
```

Which, again you can see, doesn't work correctly.

I looked at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/451475/chmod-doesnt-work) but it didn't help me. I found a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) (as my machine uses NTFS partition and the file is inside `/mnt`) on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) but I found it too complex for me.

Comment: Is the file located within the WSL `/home` or is it under `/mnt`? Filesystems in WSL1 work a bit differently than in standalone Linux, so anything that mentions "ntfs-3g" does not apply.

Comment: To elaborate on what @grawity said, check out [this](https://superuser.com/a/1322665/529800) answer from simpleuser

Comment: @grawity it's within `/mnt`.

Comment: So, you are trying to imply that there is no way of applying `chmod` unless I copy the file outside `/mnt`?

Comment: If you look how this partition was mounted, `mount | grep mnt`, do you see any mention of a `umask` or `fmask`? That is often a limitation on the permissions you can set on files on that partition.

Comment: On WSL, `/mnt` works differently from the "main" WSL filesystem, I'm not sure if it supports permission mapping at all. (The usual problem is that NTFS permissions are a bit more expressive than Linux permissions.)

Comment: @JimDanner This is what I get: ```C:\ on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
D:\ on /mnt/d type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
F:\ on /mnt/f type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
I:\ on /mnt/i type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10)